# HLOOKPUP sporatic unexpected results with time values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a HLOOKUP formula that I'm getting unexpected results from. Sometimes the lookup works based on the user inputs, other times it does not. A user is suppose to select their local time zone (AB3), their event time (AB4), and the current local hour (AB5), from drop down menus. From there a couple calculations are done with those values.

AA27 =AB4+(AB4-AB5)

AA28 =AA27-ROUNDDOWN(AA27,0) 
{This is done to remove any integer that might occur in the calculation as it would add a date of 1/1/1900 to the cell's value.}

A2:X2 all contain =VLOOKUP(AB3,A22:Y45,#,FALSE) 
{# changes based on column position from 2-25}

The HLOOKUP portion is located in cells AB5:AB18
=HLOOKUP(AA28,A2:X15,#,TRUE)
{# changes based on row position from 2-14}

With the selections in the attached image the HLOOKUP works properly. This works!
[image]

With the selection in the attached image the HLOOKUP returns 0 results when it should return Frank, Tim, Jack, and Jane. Wrong Results!!
[image]

And with this selection, the HLOOKUP returns Value Not Available. Returns error.
[image]

I've checked the returned value from AA28 & the expected cell referenced in row 2 and they don't always match exactly.

In the Returns Error example the returned value of AA28 is 1:00 AM or 0.04166666666672 while K2 is 1:00 AM or 0.0416666666666667.

In the Wrong Results example they are exactly the same. AA28 is 9:00 PM or 0.87500000000004 and G2 is also 9:00 PM or 0.87500000000004.

In the This Works example they also match. Again AA28 is 9:00 PM or 0.87500000000004 and K2 is also 9:00 PM or 0.87500000000004.

Comment: Are you able to share your sample workbook via google drive or one drive as it is difficult to regenerate your question and test the solution. Are you sure you want to use `TRUE` in your **HLOOKUP** function as it will not return an exact match. How about change that to `FALSE` and see if it worked?

Comment: If you want it to remain True then the lookup row must be sorted ascending.

Comment: @TerryW here is a link to the excel file. I originally had the HLOOKUP as FALSE but had even more issues with that. Changing it back to FALSE didn't help either.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mqjTjKLBvva_tJDgd-prnunyb-hu2Ds-